# JavaScript createElement() not affecting HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am following along with a tutorial to create an audio player. The `index.html` file has a class named `audioPlayer` as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="audioPlayer"></div>
        <script src="AudioPlayer.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `audioPlayer` class is used as a `querySelector` in the JavaScript code below in order to attach additional elements:

```
class AudioPlayer {
    constructor(selector = '.audioPlayer', audio = []) {
        this.playerElement = document.querySelector(selector);
        this.audio = audio;
        this.currentAudio = null;
        this.createPlayerElements();
    }

    createPlayerElements() {
        this.audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        const playListElement = document.createElement('div');
        playListElement.classList.add('playlist');

        this.playerElement.appendChild(this.audioElement);
        this.playerElement.appendChild(playListElement);
    }
}

let player = new AudioPlayer()
```

At this point the tutorial creator is able to access `index.html` on a local web server and verify that the `audio` and `div class="playlist></div` elements have been appended to the original selector. When I run a local server (http-server installed globally via npm) and inspect the page, this has not occurred. The `audioPlayer` element is unchanged. The console shows no error messages, and I am able to inspect the script file in the browser so I know the path is correct.

The tutorial I am following can be viewed on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZL9gVwxO-U). While the tutorial is 30 minutes long, the problem I have encountered should be reproducible by following only the first 5 minutes. The tutorial [source code](https://github.com/codebubb/javascript-audio-player) contains a `dist` directory and `package.json` showing `parcel` as a dependency.

Is it possible to create elements as attempted using only vanilla JavaScript, and if so, what am I missing?

There are many similar posts on SO. In order to avoid having this question marked as a duplicate, I will list the posts that I have carefully read and have not found pertinent to my situation:

- [Using Node.js as a simple web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/using-node-js-as-a-simple-web-server?page=1&tab=trending#tab-top)
- [Creating HTML element via javascript not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50832650/creating-html-element-via-javascript-not-working)
- [div - createElement is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453903/div-createelement-is-not-working)
- [Why doesn't a simple createElement command work with JS and create an element in HTML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891976/why-doesnt-a-simple-createelement-command-work-with-js-and-create-an-element-in)
- [Why does this document.createElement("div) code not create an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844356/why-does-this-document-createelementdiv-code-not-create-an-element)
- [Javascript: function associated with create element not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417013/javascript-function-associated-with-create-element-not-working)
- [Javascript createElement() not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861864/javascript-createelement-not-working-in-chrome)

Comment: Where is the code that does `new AudioPlayer()`?

Comment: After the class definition, I've added `let player = new AudioPlayer()`. Sorry the original code for this question did not include this, I have updated.

Comment: The video you referenced did include this in a separate file. See my answer. So, what happens now? Have you run the code with this change?

Comment: I just tried your code, including the instantiation. It appears to run fine, and creates dom elements.  Prove it to yourself by adding `playListElement.innerHTML = '<p>I am the playlist element</p>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you didn't (first) have the code that actually creates an instance of your `AudioPlayer` class, so neither `constructor()` nor `createPlayerElements()` gets executed.

In the video you referenced, check again what is discussed at around 4:10-4:30.

- In an `app.js` file enter:

  ```
  import AudioPlayer from './AudioPlayer';

  const audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
  ```
- Below the audio element in the body of your HTML, don't include `AudioPlayer.js`, but this `app.js`. So:

  ```
  <div class="audioPlayer"></div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  ```